# Alamofire AFError when work with Flickr API

Tags: ios, json, swift, alamofire

I am using Alamofire to get JSON data from flickr API.
Here if the function, which prepares an array of URLs from the response:

```
func urlTolinkslist (tag: String) {
    print (viewSearchBar.text)
    let url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?tags=\(tag.replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20"))&format=json&nojsoncallback=1"
    Alamofire.request(url).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value): 
            let json = JSON(value)
            let items = json["items"]
            self.linksList = []
            for i in 0..<items.count {
                let item = items[i]
                let media = item["media"]
                var link = String(describing: media["m"])
                self.linksList.append(link)
            }
            print("count: \(self.linksList.count)")
            self.viewCollectionView.reloadData()
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

"tag" in the API URL is the parameter I get from a search bar. In most of the cases it works fine, but in some cases I get:

```
[Result]: FAILURE: responseSerializationFailed(Alamofire.AFError.ResponseSerializationFailureReason.jsonSerializationFailed(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Invalid escape sequence around character 1029." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Invalid escape sequence around character 1029.}))
```

I think there may be some extra characters, but I don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Let Alamofire encode for you the parameters:

```
func urlTolinkslist (tag: String) {
    let url = "https://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne"
    var dict = [String:AnyObject]()
    dict["tags"] = tag
    dict["format"] = "json"
    dict["nojsoncallback"] = 1
    Alamofire.request(.GET, url, parameters: dict, encoding: .URLEncodedInURL, headers: nil).validate().responseJSON { response in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            let json = JSON(value)
            let items = json["items"]
            self.linksList = []
            for i in 0..<items.count {
                let item = items[i]
                let media = item["media"]
                var link = String(describing: media["m"])
                self.linksList.append(link)
            }
            print("count: \(self.linksList.count)")
            self.viewCollectionView.reloadData()
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work out for me. Still get the error for some of the tags.

Comment: Oups I missed something. The error is saying that the response is not a json. Can you try to use .responseString and print the result? Btw keep using the same code above as you should not encode the parameters yourself

Comment: thank you, I chained response handlers `.responseString` and `.responseJSON`. So I found in failed response the combination **\'**, which doesn't exist in successful one. I suppose, I need to get responseString, clean the response and then convert it somehow to JSON. Will try to find a way...

Comment: Having the \' in the response sounds that it's javascript specifc. Maybe there is a way to get the clean JSON without too much effort.